# Splitting arrays of complex numbers

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array with the following complex numbers. I want to make 4 different list/array with these arrays. The format would be named Arr1 ... Arr4  with r+ij, -r+ij, -r-ij, r-ij respectively.

```
A = ([ 1.23853755+1.15170502j, -1.2041678 +1.38375402j,
       1.28973689+1.2755069j ,  -1.29422454-1.28925842j,
       -1.33236945-1.22467046j,  1.25472049+1.27488595j])
```

Do you have any idea, how i could code this? I have a data of over 10k complex numbers. These are basically constellation symbols for QPSK. Any idea will be appriciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Just to clarity, `-r+ij` means you want to multiply real part with -1 and imaginary part with +1?

Comment: No, i want to split each complex numbers and make a different array with all same kind of complex numberes. For example r+ij in one array with all positive real and positive imaginary numbers in one array and so on. with real and imaginary numbers processing from 4 quadrants.

Comment: ah ok, got it. its basically breaking an array into chunks based on conditions

Comment: the format would be retained in form of r+ij, no modification intended, just taking out a number and putting in a different basket.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a completely vectorized method without any iterations (except last step).

The steps followed -

1. Stack the real and imaginary parts to get a `(6,2)` array
2. Create a boolean array for signs for each of the quadrant
3. Take `np.where` to get a boolean for the `(6,2)` array is positive and negative.
4. Take XNOR `~(a^b)` between the signs and the (6,2) boolean with broadcasting `(4,1,2)^(1,6,2)->(4,6,2)` and take then `np.all` over `axis=-1` to get `(4,6)` matrix that tell you which of the 6 complex number lies in with of the 4 quadrants.
5. Finally, we have to iterate over the boolean and index the original array A because each of these would have a different length and you cant store it as a numpy array. Therefore I have stored it as a dict.

```
A = np.array([ 1.23853755+1.15170502j, -1.2041678 +1.38375402j,
              1.28973689+1.2755069j ,  -1.29422454-1.28925842j,
              -1.33236945-1.22467046j,  1.25472049+1.27488595j])

coords = np.vstack([A.real, A.imag]).T

labels = ['r+ij', '-r+ij', '-r-ij', 'r-ij']
signs = np.array([[True,True], [False,True], [False,False], [True,False]]) #r+ij, -r+ij, -r-ij, r-ij

boolean = np.all(~(signs[:,None]^np.where(coords>0,True,False)[None,:]), axis=-1) #XNOR with broadcasting

#boolean - 
# [[ True False  True False False  True]  
#  [False  True False False False False] <- second number in '-r+ij'
#  [False False False  True  True False]
#  [False False False False False False]] <- no number in 'r-ij'

output = {labels[i]:A[j] for i,j in enumerate(boolean)}
output
```

```
{'r+ij': array([1.23853755+1.15170502j, 1.28973689+1.2755069j ,
        1.25472049+1.27488595j]),
 '-r+ij': array([-1.2041678+1.38375402j]),
 '-r-ij': array([-1.29422454-1.28925842j, -1.33236945-1.22467046j]),
 'r-ij': array([], dtype=complex128)}
```

Comment: Wondersul use of boolans Akshay, i did it in rather simpler way using the loop. It somehow worked.

Comment: yup, but would be too expensive to use a loop. but if it works, all good!

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful use of boolans Akshay, i did it in rather simpler way using the loop. It somehow worked.

```
Arr1 =[] # empty lists
Arr2 =[]
Arr3 =[]
Arr4 =[]


for u in A:
    if type(u) == complex:
        continue
    if u.real > 0 and u.imag >0: # 1st quadrant constellation points 
        Arr1.append(u)
    elif u.real <0 and u.imag >0: # 2nd quadrant cp
        Arr2.append(u)
    elif u.real <0 and u.imag <0: # 3rd quadrant cp
        Arr3.append(u)
    elif u.real>0 and u.imag<0: # 4th quadrant cp
        Arr4.append(u)
        
Arr1 = np.array(Arr1) # changing lists into array for calculation purpose
Arr2 = np.array(Arr2)
Arr3 = np.array(Arr3)
Arr4 = np.array(Arr4)
```